# Remove objects from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two classes, Image and Channel.Image has an imageId and Channel has a channelId which uniquely identify an Image and Channel object.Some other attributes are also present.

Image class also has a channelId, using which I determine to which channel the image has been assigned to.
I have a two ArrayLists of Image and Channel respectively.

```
    List<Image> imageList = getItemist("image");
    List<Image> channelList = getItemList("channel");
```

Now, I would like to remove all those image objects from the image list which contain channelId which are present in the channel objects of the channelList.

As of now, I am iterating the two lists and then comparing the channelId, putting the Image objects in a TreeSet and finally returning a list.Can you please help me with a solution that is simpler or more efficient ?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good use-case for a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

```
ListIterator iter = imageList.listIterator(); 
Image curr = null;
while (iter.hasNext){
    curr = iter.next();
    for (Image img : chanelList){
        if (img.chanelId == curr.chanelId){ //assuming chanelId is a primitive 
            iter.remove(curr); //remove curr 
            break; //break from the for loop to go on to the next image in imageList
        }
       //implicit: else continue; (i.e. go on to check the next image in chanelList)
    }
}
```

Note that this is an O(n^2) algorithm that won't scale well for large list sizes. There are ways to optimize it further (see @dasblinkenlight's comment, for one), but for purposes of conceptual clarity, I'll limit the scope of this answer to this.

Comment: Put `chanelList` into a hash set to make it `O(img+chn)` rather than `O(img*chn)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - yeah, I know. one step at a time, though. see edit.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: As far as I know removing a element from a `ArrayList` is in `O(n)`, which would make this algorithm `O(img² * chn)` instead of `O(img*chn)`.

Comment: @fabian You're right, it's n^2 for array lists. The code says simply `List`, but the title does talk about array lists.

Comment: @fabian That is what I said in my comment above, no?

Comment: Thank you all.As suggested by you all, I am iterating the two arraylists, one inside another and storing the results in a Set.@fabian I am using TreeSet because I would like to preserve the order. I am trying to do something to avoid the O(img*chn) scenario. I will let you know if I find any.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting `n` elements to a `TreeSet` requires `O(n*log(n))` time. However you don't need the `Set` to be ordered. A `HashSet` should be faster in the average case (of course you can still be unlucky with the hash codes).

You can then modify the list based on the set:

```
HashSet<Integer> channelIds = new HashSet<>();
for (Image channel : channelList) {
    channelIds.add(channel.channelId);
}

// following removal code is specialized for lists that
// allow random access, like ArrayList
final int size = imageList.size();
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Image image = imageList.get(i);
    if (!channelIds.contains(image.channelId)) {
        imageList.set(j++, image);
    }
}
if (j < size) {
    imageList.subList(j, size).clear();
}
```